# Opening .txt file in execl()

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, exec

How can I open a `.txt` file using `execl()` function? Is there any other function in c to open a file in `gedit` in Ubuntu.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other function in c to open a file in gedit

Th easiest would be

```
system("gedit file.txt");
```

---

As a side-note you might want to look into `xdg-open`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

```
execlp("/usr/bin/gedit","gedit","text.txt",NULL);
```

general syntax of `execl()` and `execlp()`

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
```

give full path of `text.txt`